# Which command to look the path to a server

Tags: networking, dns

I am looking for a command (may be two) that can shows the path to a remote server(e.g., www.google.com).

For a server, this command first lists the DNS server I used, and then shows each network hops, when it is on the way to the given IP address, which is resolved from DNS lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two commands come to mind, though there are likely a ton more:

First, DNS Server:

```
nslookup www.google.com
```

This command will output the DNS server, and a list of ip addresses that have been found that translate to www.google.com.

Second command, is the one you want to determine route, is:

```
traceroute www.gooogle.com
```

it does not show hops, though you are able to set the max number of hops.